# CSS Media Query won't work unless I add "!important"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries

I am using `SCSS` trying to set up some media queries for `max-width: 320px` and `max-width: 768px`

I have a div with class `item-content` inside an `Owl Carousel` slide with width set to `600px` but I want to reduce the width for smaller devices. I want to use `200px` for resolution 320px wide and `300px` for resolution that is anywhere between 320 and 768.

This is what I'm using in my `_app-responsive.scss` but as you can see, I have `!important` set to the width of `item-content` because otherwise it is getting overridden even though I am on resolution of the iPhone 5 which is 320px wide.

[image]

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .home {
    section#top {
      .owl-theme {
        .owl-dots {
          top: -10%;
        }
        .owl-stage-outer {
          .owl-stage {
            .owl-item {
              .item {
                .item-content {
                  width: 200px !important;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .home {
    section#top {
      .owl-theme {
        .owl-stage-outer {
          .owl-stage {
            .owl-item {
              .item {

                h2 {
                  font-size: 16px;
                }

                .item-content {
                  width: 300px;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my overall `app.scss`

I am importing the file with the media queries last, I tried importing it before the `_app-custom.scss` but that didn't change anything.

```
@import 'app-variables';
@import '../../vendor/bootstrap-sass/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import '../../vendor/bootstrap-sass/stylesheets/bootstrap-compass';
@import '../../vendor/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
@import 'app-custom';
@import 'app-responsive';
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it, but try NOT to use #top and have a try.
Maybe the id is causing the priority.
Rather "section.top{..."

Comment: I tried it without the ID, still the same.

Comment: do you have a version of it online?

Comment: http://digital-mena.com/sites/awan/index.html I am using SASS so it's all compiling under `app.css` and it's in RTL Arabic.

Comment: replace your 768 query with this:
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px)

Comment: That did not help.

Comment: Your CSS is too specific, try to reduce the specificity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two media queries would make `width: 200px` when window is between 0px and 320px but also `width: 300px` when window is between 0px and 768px.

To solve this you can apply `width: 200px` without using a media query and only when windows size is greater than 320px use width: 300px:

```
.item-content {
    width: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 321px) {
   ...
   .item-content {
       width: 300px;
   }
}
```

And:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
   ...
   .item-content {
       width: 200px;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
   ...
   .item-content {
       width: 300px;
   }
}
```

Should also works because your issue is that the query with the `max-width: 768px` is always overwriting the media query with `max-width: 320px`